# How to keep an image with flex-grow or flex-shrink (row and column)?

Tags: css, flexbox, image-resizing

I have a parent container with class `flex` and two child containers (one with class `img-container-1` and the other with `img-container-2`) with an image inside:

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="img-container-1">
        <img 
            src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/06/27/14/32/raspberry-6368999_960_720.png" 
            alt="imagen"
        >
    </div>
    <div class="img-container-2">
        <img 
            src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/06/27/14/32/raspberry-6368999_960_720.png" 
            alt="imagen"
        >
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the CSS:

```
.flex {
  display: flex;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.img-container-1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: brown;
}

.img-container-2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

I set a flex-grow of 1, to the `img-container-1 / 2`, as there is space available, both are filled equally, I also specify that the images occupy the entire width and height, this will take the height and width of the containers `img-container-1 / 2` (right?), not the main container `flex`, as well as assigning an `object-fit: contain`, so that the aspect ratio is kept, and this is what I get (and it is what I wanted to achieve):

[image]

now I want to achieve the same, but vertically (column), therefore, to the container with the class `flex` I set `flex-direction: column` but I do not get the same result (I don't want this result):

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /*I set column*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

[image]

How can I do this:

[image]

I tried `flex-grow` or `flex-shrink` but I don't understand, I hope you can help me, (the result that you see in the last gif I achieved by placing a high of `50%` to the `img-container- 1 / 2`, but it can be done in another way or I am forced to do it with percentages - `%`).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using the `background-image` instead of your current approach, that way the only thing that changes the direction is the `flex-direction` on your container and the images adapt since your items inside are adapting.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: aqua;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-1 {
  background-color: brown;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/06/27/14/32/raspberry-6368999_960_720.png');
}

.container-2 {
  background-color: burlywood;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/06/27/14/32/raspberry-6368999_960_720.png');
}

.img {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="img container-1">
  </div>
  <div class="img container-2">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: aqua;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-1 {
  background-color: brown;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/06/27/14/32/raspberry-6368999_960_720.png');
}

.container-2 {
  background-color: burlywood;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/06/27/14/32/raspberry-6368999_960_720.png');
}

.img {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="img container-1">
  </div>
  <div class="img container-2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good, but it is not the approach I want, especially when it requires SEO, but, thanks, it is still a very good alternative, thanks for your time.